# Is adding a PPA safe?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, update-manager, software-sources

Are all PPAs safe? From where do I know which PPA refers to which packages? Can adding a PPA cause any harm? Or is it that the package when downloaded will cause harm? In particular is it safe to add `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`? Or is it more safer to install packages from official websites?

Comment: PPAs are *Personal Package Archives* so all security checks are on you to perform.  No guarantee is provided with them; as they are all 3rd party software sources. You decide your own standards as to what you'll accept; how important security is for you.

Comment: In addition, Do not ask more than 1 question in one question entitiy.

Comment: I hope the existing answer helps you, and I've flagged this question as "need more focus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are all PPAs safe?

No. Although there are [no known](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329117/124466) PPA which were solely created to spread malicious software, poorly packaged apps in a PPA can cause dependency issues.

> From where do I know which PPA refers to which packages?

Click on package details of a PPA, and you will be redirected to a page containing the list of all packages, like [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test/+packages).

> Can adding a PPA cause any harm? Or is it that the package when downloaded will cause harm?

The packages in a PPA might cause harm, not adding the PPA itself. Suppose, a PPA contains a updated version of GNOME desktop, which actually has no contents (i.e., a fake, empty package). If you add that PPA, Ubuntu will "upgrade" to that version, and as a result you will lose your graphical user interface. While such PPAs are very uncommon, there are certain PPAs which contain poorly packaged apps, which may cause dependency issues.

> In particular is it safe to add ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test?

It depends. However, since this is mentioned in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain#PPA_packages), a lot of users would use it (and any malicious packages will be reported quickly), so I would trust this PPA (but this is my opinion. You should determine on your own whether you want to add the PPA).

> Or is it more safer to install packages from official websites?

It is always safer to install packages from the official sources, with `sudo apt install name-of-software-here`.

Answer (score 0):

**In short: You have to trust the developer of the PPA.**

PPAs are Personal Package Archives, a service provided by Canonical. Even though the hosting service is official, the programs inside of PPAs are all third-party programs. Use them at your own risk.

The *action itself* of adding PPAs onto your computer does nothing dangerous, but you have to download the programs at your own risk.

> You decide your own standards as to what you'll accept; how important security is for you. – [@guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152)

---

##### Are all PPAs safe?

**No.** As I said, PPAs are third parties, so they cannot be 100% trusted.